# No Service provider for e only on logger

Tags: angular, typescript, error-logging

Upgraded my app angular2 to 4, after the upgrade the only issue in prod build file.

**No service provider for e on using logger.**

in Module file:

```
import { Logger } from "angular2-logger/core";
providers:[Logger ]
```

Once occur on adding below line in my component

```
import { Logger } from "angular2-logger/core";
constructor(private logger: Logger, private trigramService: TrigramService){}  

this.trigramService.getTrigram(projectInfo).subscribe(
    values => {
      this.changes = values;
    },
    (err) => this.logger.error(err),
    () => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.lastUpdated = new Date();
    }
  );
```

This issue occurred after the upgrade and only on prod build, after removing logger  working fine.

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: You should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nsalaun/ng-logger, easier to integrate and better aot integration. I think that the issue is with aot because prod build = aot, and angular2-logger is probably not aot-compliant.

Comment: @Supamiu true. This logger work until angular v4.0.2

Comment: thx for the comment , what is the issue with angular2-logger/core and  should i replace or can I fix on the same ?